# Wait to execute the directive until the controller value is updated in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a controller variable which is populated from a server facade call. At the same time the variable is refereed in a directive defined in that controller. (variable name: *controllerReferredValue*)

When the page is loaded for multiple times, the directive will be called first without waiting until the new value is updated in the controller (from the server facade call). So the directive will always have the previous value of the variable.

But I need to call the directive once the controller value is properly updated

How can we ask the directive to be waited until the controller value is updated and then use it in directive ??

```
'use strict';

angular.module('Common.directives')
    .directive('directiveTemplate', function (resourceManager) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: resourceManager.templateUrl,
            scope: {
                controllerReferredValue: '='
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-if="controllerReferredValue"` in the tag with your directive. In this case, the directive won't be initialized unless the variable gets non-falsy value.

Comment: No the problem is not for the initial loading. once the directive is called multiple times, it always updated with the previous controller variable value. (I updated the question as well)